# Installing an exe with Powershell DSC Package resource gets return code 1619

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, p4v, dsc

I'm trying to use Powershell DSC's Package resource to install an exe... Perforce's P4V to be specific. Here's my code:

```
Configuration PerforceMachine
{
    Node "SERVERNAME"
    {
        Package P4V
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Name = "Perforce Visual Components"
            Path = "\\nas\share\p4vinst64.exe"
            ProductId = ''
            Arguments = "/S /V/qn" # args for silent mode
            LogPath = "$env:ProgramData\p4v_install.log"
        }
    }
}
```

When running this, this is the error Powershell gives me:

```
PowerShell provider MSFT_PackageResource failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message: The return code 1619 was not expected. Configuration is likely not
correct
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderOperationExecutionFailure
    + PSComputerName        : SERVERNAME
```

According to [documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290158), return code 1619 means the MSI package couldn't be opened. However, when I manually log in to the machine and run "**\\nas\share\p4vinst64.exe /S /V/qn**", the install works flawlessly.

Does anyone know why this is failing? Alternately, can anyone tell me how to troubleshoot this? I pasted all the error information I got from the terminal, my log file (p4v_install.log) is a 0 byte file, and there are no events in the event viewer. I don't know how to troubleshoot it any further!

**EDIT**: I should note that I also tried using the File resource to copy the file locally, and then install it from there. Sadly, that met with the same result.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have an answer for you, but I wanted to suggest you to write your question in the forums at the [powershell.org community forums for DSC](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/forum/dsc-desired-state-configuration/) too. If you don't get an answer here perhaps someone there can help you and you can write up an answer to your own question here afterwards.

Comment: I posted the same question there. I'll update both places whenever I find an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Daniel over at the [Powershell.org](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/installing-an-exe-with-powershell-dsc-package-resource-gets-return-code-1619/) forums was able to figure this out for me.

The P4V InstallShield setup wrapper puts the MSI file into wrong path if you execute as *LocalSystem*.

I’ve managed to develop a Configuration that works, see below. The key is the /b switch here which puts the MSI file into a defined location. I’ve added `ALLUSERS=1` to get the shortcuts visible to all users and `REBOOT=ReallySuppress` to avoid a sudden restart (which will happen otherwise).

```
Configuration PerforceMachine
{
    Package P4V
    {
        Ensure = "Present"
        Name = "Perforce Visual Components"
        Path = "C:\My\p4vinst64.exe"
        ProductId = ''
        Arguments = '/b"C:\Windows\Temp\PerforceClient" /S /V"/qn ALLUSERS=1 REBOOT=ReallySuppress"' # args for silent mode
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, what happens here is that the package gets installed (not tested with p4vinst64.exe yet! So, not sure why it says pack cannot be opened as the error) but since you did not specify a `ProductID` value, the verification at the end of install fails. That is the error you are seeing. The `Package` resource is no good for installing .exe packages or even MSIs with no ProductID represented as a GUID.

You can use the `WindowsProcess` resource instead.